# How do I add rows within python arrays that are indexed by elements of another array?

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am trying to find out the 3 nearest neighbours of a row within a set of 10 rows(each 10 rows is a class), and then average out those 3 neighbours.

I need to do this over an array of 400 rows, where each consecutive 10 rows belong to one class.

I think I have managed to capture the 3 nearest neighbours for each row within 'indices' below.
In the output below, 'indices' is a 10x3 matrix.
I'm just not sure how to go about referencing those particular 3 rows in the original xclass that the 3 elements of each row of 'indices' refers to, and then add them (the challenge) and then divide by 3 to get the average (i assume this division is straight-forward).

Updated this para after the responses below:
Basically, X has dimensions 400x4096
Indices could be for example [[1,3,5],[2,4,8].....]
What I need to do is average out rows 1,3 and 5 of X and obtain a resultant row of shape 1x4096.
Similarly average out rows 2,4,8 of X and obtain a new row for this set and so on for each row in indices.
So basically each element in a particular row of indices refers to a specific row in X.
'''

```
for counter in range(0,399,10):
    #print(counter)
    xclass=X[counter:counter+9]
    yclass=y[counter:counter+9]
    #print(xclass)
    nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='brute').fit(xclass)
    distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(xclass)
    #print(indices)
```

'''

appreciate any insight.

Comment: Do you mean [counter:counter+10], because [counter:counter+9] only slices 9 items?

Comment: Yes, its separate slices of 10 rows that form a class from the overall data set (X) of 400 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can index lists in python using a word as such...

```
a = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']

b = a[a.index('aaa')]

print(b)

output: aaa
```

and also like...

```
a = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']


word = 'aaa'
b = a[a.index(word)]

print(b)

output: aaa
```

so can do something like...

```
a = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']


word = 'aaa'
b = a[a.index(word+1)]

print(b)

output: bbb
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using numpy (or something similar). In general, you can take any indexing array and use that to capture the particular entries of interest in another array. For example,

```
import numpy as np

#Accessing an array by an indexing array. 
X = np.arange(30).reshape(6,5) #6, 5 long vectors
I = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5]]          #I wish to collect vectors 0,1,2 together and vectors 3,4,5 together
C = X[I,:]                     #Will be a 2 by 3 by 5. 2 collections of 3 5-long vectors.
print(C)    

#Computations for averaging those collected arrays. 
#Note that C is shape (2,3,5), we wish to average the 3s together, hence we need to 
#average along the middle axis (axis=1). 
A = np.average(C,axis=1)
print(A)
```

More detail about `X[I,:]`. In general, what we did here was specify all the x-coordinates and all the y-coordinates to capture in our array X. Since, we wanted the full vectors in X we didn't care about the y-coordinates and wanted to capture all of them, hence `:`. Likewise, we wanted to pull the x-coordinates 3 at a time, so we specified to pull [0,1,2] and then to pull [3,4,5]. You could change those to any indexes you wish.

Comment: Basically, X has dimensions 400x4096 Indices could be for example [[1,3,5],[2,4,8].....] What I need to do is average out rows 1,3 and 5 of X and obtain a resultant row of shape 1x4096. Similarly average out rows 2,4,8 of X and obtain a new row for this set and so on for each row in indices. So basically each value in a particular row of indices refers to a specific row in X.